# When to Recycle, Recycles, Recyclables, Recycling

Tags: word-choice

I always feel like I pick the wrong "recycle"-based word. When do I use what?

Confusing examples:

- Is it a recycle bin, recycles bin, recycling bin?
- Do I take the recycles out or the recycling out?
- Is it recycling day or recycles day?

Especially in contrast to "garbage" and the analogous forms of garbage in the above examples.

Comment: I prefer recycling on all counts

Answer (score 1):

According to [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycling_bin), it's either a recycle bin *or* a recycling bin. However, I personally have heard people say recycle bin more often, especially when referring to the digital type.

As a noun - meaning the papers themselves - I say "recycling." It seems gramatically similar to the word "stuffing." So I'd take the *recycling* out.

According to [the city of New York's official website](http://www1.nyc.gov/nyc-resources/faq/521/when-is-my-garbage-or-recycling-day), it would be called *recycling* day.

Comment: the Wikipedia article says "A recycling bin is a container used to hold **recyclables**". Seems like that article (and a few it links to) prefer "Recyclables" as the noun. "Take the recyclables out to the recycling bin on recycling day"?

Comment: [Ngrams shows 'recycling bin' to be more popular than 'recycle bin'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recycling+bin%2C+recycle+bin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecycling%20bin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecycle%20bin%3B%2Cc0)